# Problem with two send responses: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, server

I try to make a small 'database' where I can put some data into an input field and also make queries. For instance when I write a name into the field and click on the request button it will show the information about that person.
It works pretty well and also it shows a message when nothing was found. But I always get the error mentioned in the title, I can't understand what's wrong.

```
server.post('/MyWebApp/mydatabase1', function(req, res){        
    database.forEach(element => {
        if(element.email == req.body.email || element.nachname == req.body.nachname || element.vorname == req.body.vorname)
            res.send(element);
    });
    res.send("No Entry found");
});
```

first I wanted to check if any element is matching, if yes it should `res.send(element);`
if not `res.send("No Entry found");` 
it works though I get that error

> 'Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent
>   to the client'

Is it maybe because I made two send responses?
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you're sending outside of the callback function - which will always happen (`res.send` is not like `return` - it does not terminate the function).

It also looks like you're attempting to send back multiple elements. You're either looking for one element, or you're sending back an array of matching elements - but you can't send them back one at a time (think of the client side aspects of this).

Your code would look a bit like this, if you intend to return all matches:

```
server.post('/MyWebApp/mydatabase1', function(req, res) {        
    let elements = database.filter(element => element.email == req.body.email || element.nachname == req.body.nachname || element.vorname == req.body.vorname);
    if(elements.length) {
        res.send(elements);
    }
    else {
        res.send("No Entry found");
    }
});
```

If you only intend to have a single match, you can always just return `elements[0]` (if it exists).